# Login using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller that handles login:

**html**

```
<input id="UserName" type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" data-ng-model="vm.userName" placeholder="username or email">

<input id="Password" type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="password" data-ng-model="vm.password">
```

**app.js**

```
    var Call23 = angular.module("Call23", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", 'ui.bootstrap']).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: LoginCtrl, templateUrl: 'login.html' }).


        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

   Call23.factory("page", function($rootScope){
       var page={};
       var user={};
       page.setPage=function(title,bodyClass){
           $rootScope.pageTitle = title;
           $rootScope.bodylayout=bodyClass;
       };
       page.setUser=function(user){
           $rootScope.user=user;
       }
       return page;
   });

   var LoginController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, LoginFactory) {
       $scope.loginForm = {
           UserName: '',
           password: '', 
           returnUrl: $routeParams.returnUrl,
           loginFailure: false,
           loginSucess: false
       };


       $scope.login = function () {

           var result = LoginFactory($scope.loginForm.UserName, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe);
           result.then(function (result) {
               if (result.success) {
                   if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                       $location.path('/');
                   }
                   else {
                       $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
                   }
                   $scope.loginForm.loginSucess = true;
               } else {
                   $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
               }
          });
     }
  }
var LoginFactory = function ($http, $q) {
return function (UserName, Password) 
    var deferredObject = $q.defer();
    $http.post(
       'login.html', {
            Email: UserName,
            Password: Password,
        }
    ).
    success(function (data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: true });
        } else {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
        }
    }).
    error(function () {
        deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
    });
    return deferredObject.promise;
}
}
LoginFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
```

I get this error even before i try to login or build my project. 
Can you please help.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LoginFactoryProvider <- LoginFactory

Answer (score 2):

You haven't register the LoginFactory as an Angular provider, the dependency injection works if its a valid angular service/provider/factory.

If you register your function with the following code, then the LoginFactoryProvider should be found.

```
angular.module('UserLogin', [])
    .provider('LoginFactory', LoginFactoryProvider);

function LoginFactoryProvider ( /* NO-DI */ ) {
    return {
        $get: ['DI', function ($DI) {
            return {
                 setLogin: function(user, pass) { /* etc */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add in all Controllers where you want to access the `LoginFactory.setLogin` function with dependency injection as you wanted:

```
var LoginController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, LoginFactory) {
```

Ofcourse before this works you need to register the module `UserLogin` into the first part of your app.js like so:

```
var Call23 = angular.module("Call23", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", 'ui.bootstrap', "UserLogin"])
```

Comment: this is the error i found after i ve added your code im not sure if i ve done the right thing. Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DIProvider <- DI <- LoginFactory <- LoginFactory

Comment: Change the DI and $DI to the dependency modules you need (i.e. $http and $q), I add'd this as an example so you could knew where to place your DI's.

Comment: billy i'm new on angular i'm lost now

Comment: just replace ``$get: ['DI', function ($DI) {`` with ``$get: ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {``. Also if your new I would suggest to watch a few lenghty youtube presentations (like youtube.com/watch?v=_OGGsf1ZXMs)

Comment: ok thanx for your time it doesnt have error any more but my problem now is that how can i tell the code to take username and password on the database ?

Comment: Great! Well, I almost gave you all codes to get it working, you're almost done, but I suggest to figure out the last part for yourself; especially if you watch the video I posted, you should be able to grasp the concept of dependency injection and how you can use the login provider in the controller.